# Check sign_in status in Rails Devise without redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to create a page that behaves differently based on signed in status.
For example, if a user tries to navigate away to another page it should open a dialog asking to sign up, whereas if the user is already signed in, she/he will just browse away with no issue.

I was trying to use something like this:

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to @post %>
<% else %>
  <a href = '#' id = 'registration_modal'><a>
<% end %>
```

Where a jQuery handler opens up a modal when `$("registration_modal")` is clicked.

However in order to do this I need to have already called `authenticate_user!` inside the controller. But if I do that it will just redirect the user to sign in page instead of rendering this page to begin with.

I was wondering if there's a simple way to handle this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying they don't need to be authenticated for the current controller which the page above is displayed for?  If so, then you don't need to call `authenticate_user!` in that controller.  `current_user` or `signed_in?` will worked whether you called `authenticate_user!` in the associated controller or not.  You'd need `authenticate_user!` in the controller linked to by `link_to @post`.  Or do you need `authenticate_user!` on the current controller?  Perhaps you could just skip it for the action that shows your page?

Comment: Thanks I thought I had to authenticate_user! all the time but turns out that it's not. If you want you could just write the same thing  below and I will accept it as answer. But regardless, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments above, the solution is to not call `authenticate_user!` on the controller which shows the view whose code you pasted in the question.  Then the user won't be redirected to the login page immediately.  `current_user` or `user_signed_in?` will work whether or not you called `authenticate_user!` in the controller, so the view will work fine.  Instead, you can call `authenticate_user!` on the controller which `link_to @post` goes to, to ensure that *that* controller is protected behind a login.

If you only want to ensure login is needed for certain actions in a controller, you can always use the standard `:except` or `:only` parameters for the filter.  For example:

```
before_filter authenticate_user!, :except => [:an_action, :another_one]
```

I'd prefer `:except` to `:only` in this case, because it effectively whitelists methods that don't need authentication, so any new ones you add will need authentication unless they were added to the list, whereas `:only` would mean new methods wouldn't require authentication unless you added them to the list.  So `:except` is more secure by default, which is always good!  On this theme, if you want to be secure by default across your app, you could go further and add a `before_filter authenticate_user!` to your `ApplicationController` and then where you don't want authentication in your child controllers, you could use `skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:an_action, :another_one]`.  If Rails 4 is being used, it's `before_action` and `skip_before_action`.